# Memory leak when returning `std::suspend_always` from `promise_type::final_suspend`

Tags: c++, memory-leaks, c++-coroutine

I created the following simple coroutine example:

```cpp
#include <cassert>   // std::assert
#include <coroutine> // std::suspend_never, suspend_always
#include <cstdio>    // printf

class test {
public:
  class promise_type {
  public:
    explicit promise_type() {}

    void get_return_object() const {}

    std::suspend_never initial_suspend() const { return {}; }

    void unhandled_exception() const { assert(false); }

    void return_void() const {}

    std::suspend_always final_suspend() const noexcept { return {}; }
  };
};

test process() {
  co_return;
}

int main() {
  process();
}
```

Compiling this with GCC (with `-fcoroutines`) or Clang and then running the executable with Valgrind produces the following output:

```
==135311== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==135311== Copyright (C) 2002-2022, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==135311== Using Valgrind-3.20.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==135311== Command: test
==135311== 
==135311== 
==135311== HEAP SUMMARY:
==135311==     in use at exit: 40 bytes in 1 blocks
==135311==   total heap usage: 2 allocs, 1 frees, 72,744 bytes allocated
==135311== 
==135311== 40 bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 1 of 1
==135311==    at 0x4842003: operator new(unsigned long) (vg_replace_malloc.c:434)
==135311==    by 0x1091BE: process() (test.cpp:25)
==135311==    by 0x109466: main (test.cpp:28)
==135311== 
==135311== LEAK SUMMARY:
==135311==    definitely lost: 40 bytes in 1 blocks
==135311==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==135311==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==135311==    still reachable: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==135311==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==135311== 
==135311== ERROR SUMMARY: 1 errors from 1 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

This memory leak is not reported when returning `std::suspend_never` from `promise_type::final_suspend`. However, according to https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/coroutines and many other sources, resuming a coroutine after `promise_type::final_suspend` has been called is undefined behavior. Is this memory leak expected or can I do something else to prevent it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is the responsibility of your coroutine machinery to actually clean up the coroutine when your machinery is finished with it. In typical cases, `test` would store a `coroutine_handle` which it would dutifully `destroy` in its destructor. In other cases, handles are given out to other code which itself is responsible for destroying them.

In your case, you would need the promise to destroy the handle somewhere in `final_suspend`.

Put simply, ownership over the `coroutine_handle` is your code's responsibility. Coroutines cease to exist only when you make them.

Answer (score 1):

It is expected as the coroutine frame isn't destroyed. This coroutine's first suspend point is also its final suspend point (since you return `std::suspend_always`.) So, the coroutine suspends, returns control back to `main` and `main` returns without destroying the coroutine frame.

You should either manually call `destroy()` on the coroutine's handle or return `std::suspend_never` in `final_suspend`. If the coroutine doesn't suspend in its final suspend point, it clears the coroutine frame automatically.

Comment: Okay, that sounds reasonable. But then isn't this documentation about undefined behavior when returning `std::suspend_never` from `promise_type::final_suspend` misleading?

Comment: @FelixSchütz The docs mention that It's undefined behavior to *resume* a coroutine suspended at its final suspension point. That means that the proper way to destroy that coroutine is through `destroy()` and not `resume()`.